# GeForce 8600M GT: Nouveau performance better than proprietary driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, performance, nouveau

After installing Ubuntu 12.10 on this computer, I installed NVIDIA's proprietary driver, since I might want to play a few games. I soon started having problems with video and audio. I'd be watching a YouTube video, and it'd frequently “stutter”, that is, repeat the last few seconds of audio or skip a few seconds. The same happened while listening to some music, from either Rhythmbox or Banshee.

I booted up Ubuntu 13.04 from a USB stick and noticed that video and audio ran smoothly. I then attributed that to improvements to packages since version 12.10, and installed 13.04 on the machine instead. I installed the `nvidia-current` package right after booting into the system, and problems persisted. `nvidia-current-upgrades`, `nvidia-experimental` and other packages had the same problem.

I then thought that my problems could be related to the driver in use, since the LiveCD uses nouveau. I then replaced `nvidia-current` by nouveau and *voilà*, everything works just fine.

My question is: is there any tweaking required in order to get the proprietary driver running smoothly with the GeForce 8600M GT? I want to be able to play games and NVIDIA's driver has better 3D accelaration support, from what I've read.

---

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G84M [GeForce 8600M GT] (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
0e:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
0e:06.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
0e:06.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
```

Comment: Hi rberaldo, please read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card

Comment: @LuisAlvarado thanks for commenting. That page is pretty comprehensive but it unfortunately doesn't have any information on what I'm asking, I'm afraid. Installing drivers or understanding the difference between the proprietary driver and nouveau isn't a problem for me. I just can't get my mind around that nouveau is performing better than NVIDIA's driver, or understand why audio is affected.

Comment: but did you at least try installing the PPA mentioned there and testing with that, specially for your case (8600M GT). For the performance of Nouveau I am actually happy seeing it win in cases like this.

Comment: Yes, I did try installing the drivers from the PPAs mentioned. The result was the same as with the stock drivers. It's pretty cool that the laptop is completely usable with nouveau, though.

Comment: Can you please provide the laptop model. That might help figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: It's a Compal FL92. Here http://www.avadirect.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=397 is a post with system specs. I'll add the output of `lspci` to my question, too.

Comment: good link. Will wait for lspci. Maybe also dmesg if it shows something related to the video card.